# How to check for non-zero results in json response object using jQuery ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, size, response

I just need to check if there are some non-zero results in my response object, without having to run a loop ($.each or something) and increment a counter (although I can break the counting after the first iteration). I guess I can use jQuery's $.size() which returns 1 and 0 if there were results and there were no results respectively. I searched in http://api.jquery.com/size/ but did not find the confirmation. Any ideas ?

Here is my simple code -

```
         $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: postdata,
            async: false,
            url: posturl,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(response)
            {
                var results = response.allResults;
                alert($(results).size()+" and "+results.length);

                //alerts "0 and 0" - when no results
                //alerts "1 and undefined" - when there are 1 or more results

            }
        });
```

In the backend PHP logic -

```
//some array with key value pairs
$results = $this->_something($idsArray);
echo json_encode(array("allResults" => $results));
```

**Update**
I have already tried with the `length` property and you can see in my code example that it alerts `undefined` when there are non-zero results.

Output of `console.log(response.allResults);`

When there are non-zero results -

```
Object { 109="add_offline_pack_test", 110="add_offline_pack_test1", 111="add_offline_pack_test2", more...}
```

When no results -

```
[]
```

Comment: Using `results.length` should work. Have you tried printing out `response` to the console to check what `response.allResults` equates to?

Comment: I'd take a look at the raw JSON being returned by the call. From the results you're reporting, it's like the `array("allResults" => $results)` is returning `nil` rather than an empty array for no results, which seems odd.

Comment: Just checked the log, check my update

Comment: @SandeepanNath: What you've quoted isn't JSON. Again, I'd look at the raw JSON being *returned* by the call (you can do this in any modern browser using its developer tools).

Comment: From that console output it seems like `response.allResults` is an object rather than an array. `Object` has no `length` attribute in JavaScript. Looks like something to resolve server-side.

Comment: That is; in the JSON you will probably see: `"allResults": { ... }` rather than `"allResults": [{...}, {...}, {...}]`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem appears to be that although you're thinking of `allResults` as being an array, it actually isn't - it's still a key-value pair object - *except when it's empty!*

This happens because PHP's `json_encode` only treats an array as a "real" array if the keys are all integers, and contiguous starting from zero, or if the array is empty.  Otherwise it treats the array as an associative array of key-value pairs.

Hence your test can simply be *does the length property exist?*

```
if (results.length === undefined) {
    // results is an object of key:value pairs
} else {
    // results is an array
    if (results.length) {
        throw "expected empty array isn't!";
    }
}
```

As you're using jQuery you could also use `$.isArray()` to test whether you've received an (empty) array instead of an object.

Answer (score 0):

Try `length` instead of size..

Comment: Look at the question again: He did.

Answer (score 0):

Because `$results` is an array of *key-value* pairs (instead of just values), `json_encode` will encode it to an object (since objects have key-value pairs) when you have any results, but an empty array when there are none (because `$results` is an array).

So when there are no results, the result you get from `response.allResults` is an empty array (thus its length is 0). When there are results, the result you get is an object with those results. Objects do not have a length member, so it's undefined.

When you do `$(obj)`, where `obj` is some object (not array), the result is an object like this:

```
{ 0: obj, length: 1 }
```

When you do `$(arr)`, where `arr` is some array, the result is an object like this:

```
{ length: arr.length, 0: arr[0], 1: arr[1], etc. }
```

Because your result is an empty array when there are no results, the object returned by `$(result)` will then be like this:

```
{ length: 0 }
```

So if you have results, `$(result)`'s length will be 1 (because it was given an object), and if you don't have results, it will be 0 (because it was given an empty array). `$.size` simply returns `$.length`, as stated in the doc page you linked to.

Answer (score 0):

Simple use this code:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: postdata,
        async: false,
        url: posturl,
        dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        if (response.d.results == undefined) {
           //do that
        }
        else {
           //do that
        }
    },
    error: function (response) {
        // do that
    }
});
```

I hope that helps. With response.d.results.length You can get a number of rows from query.